# how to have user controlled input in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, user-input

I'm having a problem displaying the data without the program only allowing the user to input one number

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayEvenNumber {

        public static void main (String[] args)
        {

            int i,x,a[] = new int[10];



            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


            //user input
            for(i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
             System.out.println("Enter Number :");
             System.out.println("Enter -1 When Finished");
             a[i] = input.nextInt();
             //printing the data
             System.out.println("The integers you've entered are : ");
             for (i=0;i<a.length;i++)
                System.out.println(a[i]);


            }

            System.out.println("Even Numbers are :-");
            //showing the even numbers
            for(i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
                x=a[i]%2;
                if(x==0)
                System.out.println(a[i]);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: your second for loop, where you print the data is inside of your first for loop. You are essentially trying to print data that hasn't been entered yet.

Answer (score 1):

You need to print the data ONLY WHEN YOU ARE DONE putting in the data.

```
 for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
     System.out.println("Enter Number :");
     System.out.println("Enter -1 When Finished");
     a[i] = input.nextInt();

    }
//printing the data
     System.out.println("The integers you've entered are : ");
     for (i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        System.out.println(a[i]);
```

Also, I noticed your overall code could use some improvement:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


System.out.println("Enter Number :");
System.out.println("Enter -1 When Finished");

int entered = 0;
int counter = 0;
while(counter < a.length) {
     entered = input.nextInt();
     if(entered == -1) break;
     a[counter] = entered;
     counter++;
}


 System.out.println("The integers you've entered are : ");
 for (i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    System.out.println(a[i]);
 }
```